# How to filter unauthentified users and show a login form without starting the session?

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

My situation is:

1. I have a servlet which should not be accessible by unauthentified users. This servlet does some business logic and passes some intermediary data to a jsp `secret.jsp` via `RequestDispatcher::forward()`. (`secret.jsp` is just an example, there will be many servlets and/or jsps).
2. There is also a login jsp `login.jsp`.
3. In front of the servlet sits a filter which should redirect to `login.jsp` all the requests from unauthentified users. Basically `doFilter()` looks like:

   ```
   HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
   HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

   if(-1 == req.getRequestURI().indexOf("login.jsp")) {//if page which is not whitelisted
       HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
       if(null == session) {
           RequestDispatcher rd = req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp");
           rd.forward(request, response);
       }
       else {
           //not whitelisted but already logged in...
           log("we are logged in");
       }
   }

   chain.doFilter(request, response);
   ```

The problems are

1. The forward in the servlet makes the filter be triggered 2*2=4 times (twice, because it goes back and forth, as the request comes in, and as the response is delivered). I would like it to be triggered only once (when the initial request comes in) - or at least only twice.
2. The session is started. I do not want the session to be started until the user hasn't actually been successfully authenticated (i.e. sending the JSESSIONID cookie to the client).

What is the most elegant way to fix these issues?

I would like not to redirect by sending the browser a `Location` header, but instead do it internally.

**Addendum**

`secret.jsp`:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*"%>
<%@taglib prefix="tags" uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/tag_library.tld" %>
<tags:wrapper title="hello world">
    hello ${requestScope.msg} 
</tags:wrapper>
```

which uses the tag in 
`wrapper.tagf`:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@tag pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@attribute name="title" required="true" type="java.lang.String" %>
<%@attribute name="menu" type="java.util.HashMap<String, Object>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/default.less"/>
        <script src="js/less-1.1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>${pageScope.title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leftMenu">menu</div>
        <div id="body">
            <jsp:doBody/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The forward in the servlet makes the filter be triggered 2*2=4 times (twice, because it goes back and forth, as the request comes in, and as the response is delivered). I would like it to be triggered only once (when the initial request comes in) - or at least only twice.*

You forgot to return after forward which caused your filter to still continue the request/response chain.

```
rd.forward(request, response);
return;
```

Calling an arbitrary Java method does surely not abruptly terminate the currently running method block and jump out of it *(expect of `System#exit()` or when it throws an exception of course, but that's a story apart)*.

---

> *The session is started. I do not want the session to be started until the user hasn't actually been successfully authenticated (i.e. sending the JSESSIONID cookie to the client).*

This is caused elsewhere than in the filter, most likely by your JSP. Add the following to top of your JSP to explicitly disable the implicit session creation by JSP:

```
<%@page session="false" %>
```

If necessary, create a `HttpSessionListener` and put a breakpoint on `sessionCreated()` method to naildown the real root cause.

Comment: Done as suggested, after accessing "TheServlet", I still get a `JSESSIONID` along with the login form.

Comment: why does the jsp start the session without my consent? I want to control that myself.

Comment: @Flavius Is there a specific reason you don't want a session? Having one does no (or very, very little) harm. In general, it's easier to check for the presence of a known session attribute in session rather than try to avoid having a session at all. JSPs create a session unless you explicitly configure them not to.

Comment: Having a session without an authentified user doesn't look right to me. Semantically speaking. Besides, that's a session started for nothing, it just pollutes the server.

Comment: That aside, did the answer help in solving the problem? Please let me if it still doesn't solve the problem.